# How can I get automatically anchors for every h2-heading?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I usually type my posts directly via the HTML textarea, but I forget quite often to add anchors to the -Elements. Can they automatically be added with the text of the heading? How can this be achieved?

Does a plugin exist for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly what I was looking for, but [Table of Contents Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/table-of-contents-plus) also adds anchors to my headings.